# Turning a IP Address into a valid URI

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, ip, uri

I have been trying to navigate my webview element in my windows store app to '192.168.0.1' but for some reason the Uri class can not parse it, is there a way to make convert a IP Address into a Uri?

Comment: While we *may* need more information, assuming you're looking for the default document in the root directory of the site, and `http` is your protocol rather than `https`, a naive solution would be: `string theUrl = "http://" + theIpAddress + "/"`.

Comment: I would give you more information but i dont know what else to say about it, but thats for the advice, i shall try it now

Comment: As much as people keep asking me for code, i dont have any to show that is relevant to this problem, i just didnt understand how something like 'new Uri("192.168.0.1")' wouldnt work

Comment: It wouldn't work, because `192.168.0.1` is not a URI. It's missing vital information, like the protocol and the specific resource you're requesting. Conversely, `http://192.168.0.1/` does resolve all those ambiguities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this is to add the prefix of the ip's protocol:

`http://` or `https://`, for instance

`new Uri("192.168.0.1")` would have to be `new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/")`

Thanks to [Bob Kaufman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35142/bob-kaufman)

Answer (score 16):

You can also use [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder) and not have to manually add the "http://".

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("192.168.0.1");
var uri = builder.Uri;
```